# SharePoint 2013 on Internet

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, internet

I want to publish my SharePoint 2013 on-premises site to the internet, any step by step guide on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I am not sure it is wise to put sharepoint available for anyone (and it will be) on the Internet.

In a nutshell, and at a basic level, you need to first ensure that you enable Anonymous Access for your web application. You'll then need to set up DNS for the domain you own to point to your web front end server (or virtual IP if it's load balanced). Then set up the appropraite IIS bindings for the web application, and finally you'll need to extend your web application to an Internet Zone and give it the appropriate domain name.

However you can find more information on the following links of how to configure sharepoint site for internet
[Link 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ced3fed-8b1c-4d53-a129-53f71e15e686/step-by-step-to-access-sharepoint-2010-intranet-site-as-publishing-internet-facing-website?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious) 
[Link 2](http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2010/06/making-a-sharepoint-2010-site-externally-available-alternate-access-mappings-host-header-bindings.html)
[Link 3](http://mroffice365.com/2011/10/how-to-open-a-sharepoint-2010-website-for-internet-access/)
[Link 4](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/how-can-i-publish-my-sharepoint-site-to-be-able-to-access-it-from-the-internet/)

Comment: Well for a public website it is not a very strange demand :)

Answer (score 1):

This is very open ended questions. Publishing a site to internet depend on requirement and available resources.

First you need the Public DNS which is accessible over the internet as Maos already mentioned how can you get this done. But couple of things to make sure.

- Do you want to expose everything to public?
- Do you want enable any authentication or anonymous access?
- Do you want only subset of content to publish online?

in some case companies just publish the news bulletin and other public related information from their intranet to internet using the [Content Deployment Method](http://curah.microsoft.com/51807/sharepoint-2013-content-deployment). witht his method you can control what you want to publish over internet or what not. Usually this type of solution required two farms, one internal and one external(which host internet site).

Another option is use the [cross site publishing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163225.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)