# Public Access to Website

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, permissions

What permissions do I need to enable to allow public browsing to my on-Premises SharePoint Website?

I built it, MasterPage and all and now I need to be able to browse it from other computers...if even to start with other network computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question you need to publish your SharePoint site to the internet that requires a cooperation with your system / network administrator and  SharePoint site administrator, it's not only permission settings as you think.

So I tried to list the main steps that help you To make SharePoint accessible from the Internet,

- A public IP address accessible from the Internet.
- Create an A-record in your DNS for your domain name for what you want that points to your public IP address.
- Set your firewall to port forward Port 80 to your internal server running SharePoint.
- Configure Alternate Access Mappings to the match the A-record you created. check also [how to configure Alternate Access Mapping inside SharePoint Server 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/26/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)
- Set the authentication provider to `anonymous` or `claims` based on your requirement

See also similar thread [SharePoint 2013 on Internet](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139341/sharepoint-2013-on-internet)